# Identify and email results

Tags: scripting

I want to identify files older than 180 days. I am doing this with:

```
find *path* -mtime +180 -exec ls -la \; > file.txt
```

The problem is, from this result set I want to send email to the various file owners telling them they have an old file.

How could I do that?

Comment: Don't `find [...] -exec ls`; just `find [...] -print`.

Comment: using the find with print option doesn't tell me owner/s

Comment: So your question is really that you have a list of user names (and maybe files) and you want to send an email to them, but you haven't told us if you know their email addresses or if you have an email server configured (e.g., sendmail or postfix).

Comment: The point being not to try to parse `ls`.  You can for instance `find -exec stat` to print out a file name and owner.

Comment: Or even `find -printf "..."` to generate a custom result per match.

Comment: DopeGhoti - i can do find [...] -print and it returns file list without any details, just the path and filename.  -printf gives me bad option.

Comment: DopeGhoti - i can do find [...] -print and it returns file list without any details, just the path and filename.  -printf gives me bad option.  This code here: find  /xxx/xxxxx/xxxx/ -mtime +1800 -exec stat \; returns this:  find: cannot execute stat:: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mail server/MTA running, such as `Postfix`, a rudimentary script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A files email_addr

# Compose array of external e-mail addresses:
# (add a line for each user with an external address)
email_addr[username1]="username1@gmail.com"

# Define a send mail function (relies on local MTA)
function sm()
{
  sendmail -t << EOF
From: System Administration <admin@yoursystem.org>
To: $1
Subject: Old file(s)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Hello $2, you have one or more old files:
$3
EOF
}

# Make list of owners and their old files
while read -r username filename; do
  files[$username]=${files[$username]}${filename}$'\n'
done < <(find /home/ -mtime +180 -type f -printf "%u %p\n" 2>/dev/null)

# Send e-mails, one to each username
for username in "${!files[@]}"; do
  sm "${email_addr[$username]:-$username}" "$username" "${files[$username]}"
done
```

The `find` command is used to create a list of usernames and filenames of old files (an "old file" is defined as a file that hasn't been modified for at least 180 days). The list is read into a `while` loop, line by line, to build a per-user list of files in an associative array named `files`. In the following `for` loop, for each identified user with one or more old files, the function `sm` (sendmail) is called to send an e-mail to the respective file owner regarding his/her old file(s).

Out of the box, a `Postfix` installation will try to deliver mail addressed to bare usernames to the traditional UNIX system accounts on the (local) machine using its local delivery agent. If delivery to an externally hosted mail account is desired, you need to provide for either an "alias map" that enables translation of the username to an external e-mail address (e.g. name@gmail.com), or fill the associative `email_addr` array in the script.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on this and report back.

Comment: forgot to mention. This could be 1 file per user but more likely many files per user.

Comment: @BradJenkins I rewrote the script a bit, so it may better fit your needs. It now sends one e-mail to every user with one or more old files; in this e-mail, all identified old files are listed. You can also specify external e-mail addresses in the script, should you wish to use these instead of the UNIX user accounts.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I will put some cycles against this this afternoon and let you know.

Comment: Ozzy - printf constantly does not work for me.  Reports as: bad option      I can man printf so i dont know why it wouldnt work

Comment: @BradJenkins -printf in the script is an option of the find command (not to be confused with, for instance, the Bash builtin). Does your manpage for find not list the printf option? Also note that there is no space between the dash and the word printf.

Comment: man for find only lists -print

Comment: @BradJenkins Aha, you are probably running a FreeBSD-flavored *nix; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/find-lacks-the-option-printf-now-what). Quickest solution seems to be installing GNU find from the findutils package. Is that feasible?

Comment: Hey Ozzy - I have moved on from the initial thoughts. Here is what I will do now.  I presently email a "sorted by file owner" list of files older than X to myself.  I will then hack that output and manually send lists by user to user.

Comment: @BradJenkins That sounds like doing scriptable work. What is the problem with the script-solution? Running a local MTA or smth else?

Comment: Ozzy - is it possible to private message here?

Answer (score 0):

```
find *path* -mtime +180 -ls | mailx -s "old files" ronald@mcdonald.com
```

Comment: it would be multiple files with different owners. I need to send the files owned by owner X only to him/her.